# How to draw a PNG on a transaprent background?

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, png, gdi+

I have a window with a WS_EX_LAYERED style and it has a alpha color key of magic pink (0xFF,0,0xFF).
I'm trying to draw a PNG image over that window using GDI+ and it shows shades of pink around the icon edges (where the alpha blend is applied).
Here's an example:

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/8241/stackoverflow.png

How can I draw the image with the real background (the one's behind my window) alpha blend and not the color key?

Thanks for help,
Omer

Comment: What are you currently using to do the drawing?

Comment: @Jon Cage Nothing special, just invoking Gdiplus::DrawImage and before that setting the window color key to magic pink. Because the background is drawn first, the alpha blending is affected from the pink color and not the real background.

Comment: Does the PNG have an actual alpha channel?  Or does it just have magenta in the background?

Comment: @Adrian - it has alpha channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points to check over:

1. Have you seen [the docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx)?
2. What options have you fed into your [BLENDFUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921335.aspx) struct?
3. How are you loading your .png?
4. Does your image have an alpha channel?

Comment: 1,2) Read it and giving a go on UpdateLayeredWindow, hope that will do it.
3) using GdiPlus::Image
4) yes